# Imported certificate to Java keystore, JVM ignores the new cert

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl-certificate, keytool

I'm trying to get an application running on top of Tomcat 6 to connect to an LDAP server over SSL.

I imported certificate of the server to keystore using:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib\security>keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file mycert -alias ca_alias -keystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

When I start Tomcat with SSL debugging turned on, according to logs Tomcat is using the correct certificate file:

```
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

However, Tomcat does not add the cert I just imported - all other certs in the cacerts file are printed to the log - and connection fails:

```
handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Restarting Tomcat does not help. I have verified with keytool -list command that the new cert indeed exists on the file.

Why Tomcat keeps on ignoring my new cert?

EDIT:

Seems that the issue was caused by Windows 7 VirtualStore. Keytool created a new copy of the cacert file, and Tomcat used the original file.

Comment: Does the file `mycert` contain the whole certificate chain? Java wants the whole trust path to be in the store.

Comment: Just a simple suggestion, go to your `C:\Users\YourAccountName`, a file names `.keystore` will be there, open it and remove your previous one from that, and then do what you did again. Hopefully that will sort things out for you :-)

Comment: @Romain No, a trusted certificate has nothing to do with the chain. Any certificate imported as a trusted certificate is treated like a trusted root certificate.

Comment: @tputkonen : My bad, that my suggestion didn't worked, seems like I am out of ideas :( Try, try and try again, that's all I can say, You will get success soon :-) My BEST WISHES WITH YOU on this :-)

Comment: @emboss (Apologies for this comment out of context, I'll delete it.) Any thoughts on this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131414/148833

Comment: @Bruno No problem, sure, I'll have a look!

Comment: "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib\security\cacerts" is not a keystore, it's the default truststore.

Answer (score 28):

JVM needs restart after importing certs to the keystore.

Comment: I realise this is an old answer to an even older question, but is this JVM behaviour documented anywhere?

Answer (score 6):

Check to see whether there is a key with the same CN information but a different alias.

I have had similar problems before when I tried to import a newer version of a certificate but left the older version in the keystore. My Java programs would simply find the first matching CN key in the keystore (which was the old expired one) and try to use that, even though there was a newer one which also matched the CN.

Also ensure that the authenticating Root certificate (and Intermediate certificate if applicable) exist in the keystore. If you're authenticating against one of the major security providers such as Verisign or Globalsign, they will usually provide you with the root and intermediate certificates. If these certificates exist in the keystore already, ensure they are still in validity. You need to have all the certificates from your personal certificate all the way down the authentication chain to the root, existing in your keystore, so that it understands how to validate your credentials.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have you checked that the Root certificate for your certification authority exists in the keystore?

Comment: You don't need to add certificates above one that is already in the trust store. Any certificate in the store is trusted without further validation. But good advice with the alias!

Answer (score 2):

What you described is exactly what I´ve been getting when using `cmd.exe` and a regular user although member of administrative group on a Windows Server. You have to start `cmd.exe` in administration mode to apply the changes in to cacerts files. At least on the Win2k8 OS´s.

If you do not do this carets will show you in the `keytool.exe -list` view the newly added certs but Tomcat won´t see them. Not sure why so. But when you do add it with cmd.exe started as Administrator Tomcat is fine with the newly added certs.

You can also use `Djavax.net.debug="ssl,handshake"` to see what Tomcat reads from cacerts file.

Comment: As the Q said a year earlier, it's [Windows VirtualStore aka file-system virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005081/how-to-detect-file-redirection-to-the-windows-virtualstore)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I looked through so many things before I figured out what was wrong... I added the certificate to different keystores, I added all certificates in the chain (which is pointless btw), I downloaded the cert again for my own sanity and checked the serial number, and even inspected the downloaded cert to make sure it had all the correct information.

I ended up writing a TLS verifying client app in order to debug the issue. Not only did the remote server I was connecting to support only TLS 1.2 (disabled by default in my version of Java 7), the server also supported none of the ciphers that were enabled in my client. It turns out Java 7 had fewer than half of its supported ciphers enabled, many of them being really insecure and some of the most secure ones were disabled.

After some cross-checking, I came up with the following ordered list of TLS 1.2-supported secure ciphers:

```
new String[] {
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM",
    "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM",
    "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM",
    "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
    "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256"
}
```

If there are any crypto experts around, feel free to update this list. I used [Qualys SSL Labs](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices#23-use-secure-cipher-suites), [this Information Security SE answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/77018/19908), and [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#table-tls-parameters-4) as my sources.

For those who want a sample of the source code I used, see below. I was using Apache Commons HttpClient 3.0, so you'll probably need to download the following binaries:

- https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/commons-httpclient/3.0/binary/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.zip
- https://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/logging/binaries/commons-logging-1.0.4.zip
- https://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/commons-codec-1.3.zip
- https://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang-2.6-bin.zip

### TLS12SocketFactory.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class TLS12SocketFactory implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory {

        private final SecureProtocolSocketFactory base;
        public TLS12SocketFactory()
        {
            this.base = (SecureProtocolSocketFactory)Protocol.getProtocol("https").getSocketFactory();
        }
        private Socket acceptOnlyTLS12(Socket socket)
        {
            if(socket instanceof javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket) {
                final javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket s = (javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket)socket;

                // Set TLS 1.2
                s.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{ "TLSv1.2" });

                // Using recommended ciphers from https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#table-tls-parameters-4
                List<String> recommended = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{ "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM", "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM", "TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM", "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256" }));
                recommended.retainAll(Arrays.asList(s.getSupportedCipherSuites()));
                if(recommended.size() == 0) {
                    System.err.println("No supported modern ciphers. Update crypto policy or install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files." + System.lineSeparator());
                } else if(recommended.size() < 3) {
                    System.out.println("Few supported modern ciphers. It's recommended to update crypto policy or install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files." + System.lineSeparator());
                }
                s.setEnabledCipherSuites(recommended.toArray(new String[0]));

                // Log matched cipher and cert
                s.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void handshakeCompleted(javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedEvent hce) {
                        String print = s.getInetAddress().getHostName() + System.lineSeparator() + hce.getCipherSuite() + System.lineSeparator();
                        try {
                            for(java.security.cert.Certificate cert : hce.getPeerCertificates()) {
                                List<String> certStrings = Arrays.asList(cert.toString().split("\r?\n"));
                                for(int line = 0; line < certStrings.size(); line++) {
                                    if(certStrings.get(line).startsWith("Certificate Extensions:")) {
                                        print += System.lineSeparator() + StringUtils.join(certStrings.subList(2, line-1), System.lineSeparator()) + System.lineSeparator();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException ex) {
                            print += "Non-certificate based cipher used" + System.lineSeparator();
                        }
                        System.out.println(print);
                    }
                });
            }
            return socket;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException
        {
            return acceptOnlyTLS12(base.createSocket(host, port));
        }
        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException
        {
            return acceptOnlyTLS12(base.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort));
        }
        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpConnectionParams params) throws IOException
        {
            return acceptOnlyTLS12(base.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort, params));
        }
        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException
        {
            return acceptOnlyTLS12(base.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose));
        }
}
```

### Main.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<java.net.URI> locations = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String arg : args) {
            java.net.URI location = java.net.URI.create(arg);
            if(location.isAbsolute() && location.getScheme().equals("https")) {
                locations.add(location);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Skipping invalid URL: " + arg);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Connecting to URL's");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

        TLS12SocketFactory tls12factory = new TLS12SocketFactory();
        Protocol.registerProtocol("httpss", new Protocol("httpss", tls12factory, 443));
        for(java.net.URI location : locations) {
            System.out.println();
            try {
                // Form request
                String tls12url = location.toString().replaceFirst("^https:", "httpss:");
                HttpMethod method = new HeadMethod(tls12url);

                // Send request
                HttpClientParams params = new HttpClientParams();
                params.setParameter(HttpClientParams.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);
                new HttpClient(params).executeMethod(method);
                method.setFollowRedirects(true);

                // Print response
                System.out.println(location.toString());
                System.out.println(method.getStatusLine().toString());
            } catch (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException ex) {
                System.out.println("There was an error making a secure connection to " + location.getHost());
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            } catch (HttpException ex) {
                System.out.println("There was an error with the external webpage");
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Could not complete request");
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        try {
            // Load supported SSL Ciphers
            System.out.println("Supported ciphers");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println();
            javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket socket = (javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket)tls12factory.createSocket("www.google.com", 443);
            for(String cipher : socket.getSupportedCipherSuites()) {
                System.out.println(cipher);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println();

            // Load enabled SSL Ciphers
            System.out.println("Enabled ciphers");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println();
            for(String cipher : socket.getEnabledCipherSuites()) {
                System.out.println(cipher);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println();

            // Load the JDK's cacerts keystore file
            String filename = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
            System.out.println("Loading keystore");
            System.out.println(filename);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println();
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            String password = "changeit";
            keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

            // This class retrieves the most-trusted CAs from the keystore
            PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(keystore);

            // Get the set of trust anchors, which contain the most-trusted CA certificates
            for (TrustAnchor ta : params.getTrustAnchors()) {
                // Print certificate
                System.out.println(ta.getTrustedCert());
            }
        } catch (CertificateException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not load keystore");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```