# How to configure LDAPS authentication on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, ldap

To start, I configure HTTPS on Tomcat and I configure a authentication page.
My authentication page work in HTTPS with an user in Tomcat-users.xml

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
       Username:<input type="text" name="j_username"><br>
       Password:<input type="password" name="j_password">
       <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

On server.xml I configure a realm

> < Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
>
> > connectionURL="ldaps://XXXXXXX:636"
> >      debug="99"
> >     
> >      connectionName="MY_USER"
> >     
> >      connectionPassword="MY PASSWORD"
> >     
> >      userbase="MY_BASE"
> >     
> >      userSearch="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
> >     
> >      userSubtree="true"
> >     
> >      roleBase="XXXXXXXXXXX"
> >     
> >      roleSubtree="true"
> >     
> >      roleName="XXXXX"
> >     
> >      roleSearch="XXXXXX"
> >
> > />

I import my certificate with the command keytool.

> > keytool -import -file om_certificat.pem -keystore cacerts

Should I do something else?

When I start tomcat, I have this warning:
[SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error)

I did this, but doesn't work !
I think, my reaml is correct and when I did the command "keytool", I receive a message "the certificate is added".

So where, is my problem ? I forget a step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem.

I add my certificate on my JVM 64bits, but my %JAVA_HOME% is configured for my 32bits version.

Answer (score 2):

If you really established the "trust" relationship with your LDAP certificate (e.g. import it to your local keystore), one problem that I commonly see is that it's imported into a keystore that's actually not used at all.

Double check (if that fails triple check) which cacerts file you import to and which one is used by tomcat)

Edit: By quick check, [here](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP) they say, you'll have to use java's default keystore for LDAP trust (the common documentation that you'll find everywhere is for SSL/HTTPS setup). The easiest way to assure this (with all of the different java versions that you might have installed on your computer) is to locate *all* of the `cacerts` files on your and import your LDAP's cert one-by-one, then restart (at least it's the easiest for me to point out without physically assisting you)

You might also want to check [Imported certificate to Java keystore, JVM ignores the new cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483828) for some more ideas

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How can I check this ?