# Adding trust cert inside a docker container

Tags: https, jvm, certificate, keycloak

I have a keycloak running inside a docker and I want to add a trusted certificate, so I ssh in to the container and copy the cert file and imported the certificate via the keytool

```
${JAVA_JDK}/jre/bin/keytool \
    -import -trustcacerts \
    -alias "efactory-nimble_salzburgresearch_at.crt" -file efac.crt \
    -keystore ${JAVA_JDK}/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
    -storepass changeit \
    -noprompt
```

The response from the key tool was,

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256m -Xms50m
Certificate was added to keystore
```

After successfully importing the certificate also Im getting this error in keycloak.

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So my question is does the jvm needs to be restarted after adding the certificate inside a docker container & does any one else also came across this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the JVM needs restart after adding the certificate to the keystore - look here: [Imported certificate to Java keystore, JVM ignores the new cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483828/imported-certificate-to-java-keystore-jvm-ignores-the-new-cert).

Other than that, you should probably have a more "persistent" way how to update the keystore since it'll be gone after the container is removed.